# Surface Pro 3 Typepad getting randomly disabled on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface-pro-3

Randomly, the typepad (touchpad + keyboard) is getting randomly disabled by the latest windows 10 update. It happens at random. Windows randomly decided to pop up the "Autorotate On" (or something) and then all input is denied while it is on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I have tried all known fixes and had Microsoft Techs check it out twice.  They verified the problem and some fixes worked temporarily. They believe the Typecover needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by the EnableCursorSupression option in the Windows Registry. To disable it, open the run box with `super+run` and type in `regedit`. Hit `enter` and select `yes` in the UAC popup.

Once regedit is open, navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS\CURRENTVERSION\POLICES\SYSTEM` Now double-click on the DWORD value called `EnableCursorSuppression` and set it to 0. If a DWORD value called `DisableCursorSuppression` exists, delete it. This can mess up setting `EnableCursorSuppression` to 0.

If the DWORD value does not exist, right click on empty space and select `DWORD (32-bit)` and name it `EnableCursorSuppression` and set the value to 0